# Failed to create GLFW window?

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, glfw, glm-math

I tried to create a window with the simplest code possible:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <GL/glew.h> // Always include it before glfw.h
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

int main(void) {
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // OpenGL 3.3
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE); // Mac

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(720, 480, "OpenGL", NULL, NULL); // Create a window

    if (window == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create window\n");
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    return 0;
}
```

This is my Makefile:

```
game:
    g++ src/main.cpp -std=c++17 -o play -I include -L lib -l glfw.3 -l GLEW.2.2
```

When I compile my code there is no error, but when I try to play my code I have this error:

```
Failed to create window
Invalid window hint 0x00000003
Invalid window hint 0x00000003
Context profiles are only defined for OpenGL version 3.2 and above
```

Can someone help me? I don't know why my window doesn't want to be created...

Comment: I tried many versions an it's still not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR` & `GLFW_VERSION_MINOR` are not valid arguments to `glfwWindowHint`:

```
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // OpenGL 3.3
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ nope
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ also nope
```

Use `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR` & `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR` instead.

As per [the docs](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/window_guide.html#window_hints), emphasis mine:

> `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR` and `GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR` specify the client API version that the created context must be compatible with. The exact behavior of these hints depend on the requested client API.
>
> Note: **Do not confuse these hints with `GLFW_VERSION_MAJOR` and `GLFW_VERSION_MINOR`, which provide the API version of the GLFW header.**

Comment: Thanks dude ! It works fine now... i'm stupid sorry.

Comment: @miishuriinu: You bet!  And thank *you* for a revision-1 [mcve]!  Those help *immensely*.